# NFC eSE: editing nfcee_access.xml to allow access to NFC card emulating App

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to make an App for LG Optimus 4x that will require it to emulate as a NFC tag. It's a simple boarding pass/ ticketing app. For that, I'm following this tutorial:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html.

I have the following confusions:

I'm not sure about the NFC controller used by the device and the availability of embedded secure element. I have rooted the device and `/etc` contains the `nfcee_access.xml` file. So, I'm assuming the device has the embedded Secure Element. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Second, The `nfcee_access.xml` file already contains a long signer hex string saying "Google Wallet Release Signature". In order to enable access to my own app, do i still have to add another signer certificate for my app or the Google Wallet's signer certificate will work for my app too? Or should I just add my package name after this already existing Signer Certificate?

If I have to add a new signer certificate, how can I get it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

as long as you don't have the keys to the embedded secure element, you won't be able to store any data in the secure element. So at the moment it doesn't make much sense investing time into this field (unless you want to read data from the secure element, which might be already stored there).

The better option is to wait for Andoird 4.4 (KitKat) and use Host Card Emulation (HCE, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html). This feature allows you to emulate your Boarding pass even without a secure element.

Other Options are disuccess here: [How to emulate a nfc-tag on an android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831994/how-to-emulate-a-nfc-tag-on-an-android-phone?rq=1)

best

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So, I should wait for the release of Android 4.4 to program the NFC card emulator mode? Are there no other options??

Comment: Hi, well yes -- this is what I would recommend. (If you have time). The new Nexus 5 already ships with Android 4.4