# Is it possible to communicate with Secure Element Applet on Android?

Tags: android, nfc

It is my understanding that Google restricts the development of anything that touches the secure element to "trusted" developers.
However, what I want to know is if it's possible to communicate with already-installed applets without any kind of special permission (perhaps root is acceptable).

For example, say there's a mastercard applet on there, is it possible to send the various APDU commands to it? I'm not looking to access or change any data that's on the UICC, I simply want to "use" an app that's stored on it. An example of another App that must do this is Google Wallet, as it communicates with other "applets" on the secure element.

Thanks.

Comment: Details on how to accomplish this are explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10506299/1202968

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. In 4.0.4 there is whitelist of packages and keys that are allowed to communicate with the secure element. If you add your app/certificate to the list, you should be able to connect. However, third party apps will most likely require authentication, and if you don't have the proper secure channel key, you won't be able to connect to the applet. What are you trying to do?

Reference to similar question with some more details: [Secure element Access Control on ICS 4.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494726/secure-element-access-control-on-ics-4-0-4/)

Comment: Hey thanks for that.
What I'm trying to do is simply send some data to an applet that's already on the Secure Element. I don't need to touch the data on the secure element myself (the applet can do that), just send some commands and grab the responses.

Essentially, I just want to be able to run some tests against an applet or several applets.

Comment: OK, but unless you know the protocol of the applet, and are sure that it doesn't require authentication, be careful. A few failed authentication attempts could lock out the secure element (Java card).