# How to store data into Secure Element in android

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s, secure-element

I want to create a google wallet like application in android. It is said that "all payment credentials are stored in a chip called the **Secure Element** contained within the phone". How can I access this *secure element* and store my card credentials into it.
My aim is to use my phone (Nexus) at the checkout counter instead of my card.

So what I want is to store some data to the Secure Element chip and access the data when I tap on an NFC reader.

Comment: These two blog articles both explain how you can use the Secure element. http://randomoracle.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/using-the-secure-element-on-an-android-device-13/ and http://nelenkov.blogspot.ca/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html Also check out this StackOverFlow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494726/secure-element-access-control-on-ics-4-0-4

Answer (score 10):

If you check the [Google Wallet FAQ](http://www.google.com/wallet/faq.html) you can find the following :

- > Your payment credentials are stored in a chip called the Secure Element contained within your phone. The Secure Element is isolated from your phone’s main operating system and hardware. Only authorized programs like Google Wallet can access the Secure Element to initiate a transaction.
- > Even Google Wallet itself has very limited access to the Secure Element, and cannot read or write data from its memory. There are multiple levels of protection for data stored on the Secure Element and it is protected at the hardware level from snooping or tampering.

So basically... you don't have access to this `SecureElement`. Maybe talking with the phone manufacturers to give you access/ ways of accessing the `SecureElement` will enable you to do this... but I think this would be out of your scope.

**EDIT:**
An alternative solution can be storing your data in an `SQLite` database, and also use `encryption` on that database, such as `AES`... or whatever you prefer. You will still have to pay attention on how you keep/distriubte the `encryption/decryption keys`.

If you are worried about the case when somebody looses his phone, and the "founder" tries to steal the data, you can implement also an password protection on your `Application` and if the password is typed wrong 3 consecutive times, drop the `SQLite` database where the data is stored.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay.
Can you suggest any alternative method to achieve what i want, ie , save the card credentials in a secure place?

Comment: If you store the card credentials in sqlite db, sooner or later it will be hacked. Granted, the phone has to be stolen and rooted first. But it will not be difficult for skilled hackers to figure out the encryption key if it is stored in the app itself. Consider storing the credentials information on the server instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store anything in the security encryption chip, since it is by design hardware separate from the operating system.

Comment: Well, secure elements are typically connected to the application processor (that's the one that runs the Android operating system). This is either a connection through the baseband modem (for UICC-based secure elements), a connection through filesystem IO for microSD-based secure elements or a connection through the NFC controller for embedded secure elements. Btw. as of Android 4+ most Android NFC devices even provide APIs (partially undocumented) to access secure elements. However, in order to store applications and data onto a secure element, you would need the keys that protect it.